# Compile time population of data structures in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, aws-lambda

The use case is an AWS Lambda function I want some data pre-loaded into it at compile time. How does one go about pre-populating data structures at compile time in Haskell? Analogous [C++ discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490498/compile-time-population-of-data-structures-other-than-arrays).

Comment: My best stab so far is to use the C++ template abuse solution and FFI to it. Complete hack, I would rather do this all in Hask.

Comment: I don't believe this is really possible, since even if you have access to the constructors of a type you have to deal with lazy evaluation.  If I put a list literal in a source file and load it into GHCi, `:sprint` shows that it hasn't been evaluated yet.  The data is still stored in the binary, but the structure itself hasn't been "put together" yet.

Comment: I think it should be possible to achieve this with template-haskell.

Comment: There are some tricks you can play if you want unboxed vectors, where you use the fact that string literals are actually C strings. I don't remember the trick exactly, but I think it involves `Addr#` or some such. If you want anything with pointers in it, you're going to have much more trouble because of the linker and such, and at that point you should probably give up.

Comment: BTW, "Hask" is normally not used as shorthand for the name Haskell, but rather as the name of the mathematical almost-category of Haskell types and functions.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? I could write a satisfactory answer if you showed me what exactly you needed doing.

Comment: Key value pair hash map. Keys could be either 64 bit ints or small strings.